# Best way to represent a field in an Object that comes from and ID+Name from the DB?

Tags: c#, class, business-objects

I have this (simplified for illustration puprposes) object, which represents a table with fields (id,type,brand,model,price) from a DB. For type,brand, and model, only the Id's are stored, which have a relationship to the Types, Brands and Models database. With a few joins, the objects loads the data and gets also the Name properties for them:

```
public class Car
{

    public int TypeId;
    public int BrandId;
    public int ModelId;
    public decimal Price;

    public string TypeName;
    public string BrandName;
    public string ModelName;

}
```

This lets the object structure "dirty" in my opinion. What is the best way to load this into more structured objects, like:

```
public class Car
{
    public Definitions.CarTypes Type;
    public Definitions.CarBrand Brand;
    public Definitions.CarModel Model;
    public decimal Price;
}
```

My concern is how would the data be filled inside the object when the query is returned from the database. Is using a constructor (thisCar.Brand = new CarBrand(reader["id"],reader["name"]); for each field a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is to use Enums. Enums can be of various underlying types, but the default is Int. You can explicitly set the int value of each element in an Enum, which is useful for making them match some other predefined list (like error codes, or in your case: unique ids of items in your DB).

Your code that parses you data-set and creates your "Car" objects can simply cast those database row ids into the corresponding Enum.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.Brand = (CarBrand)1;
        myCar.Model = (CarModel)10;
        myCar.Type = (CarType)3;

        Console.WriteLine("You drive a {0} {1} {2}. Niiiice.", myCar.Brand, myCar.Model, myCar.Type);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

public class Car
{
    public CarType Type {get; set;}
    public CarBrand Brand {get; set;}
    public CarModel Model {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}


public enum CarBrand
{
    BMW = 1,
    Audi = 2,
    Ford = 5,
    Volkswagen = 23
}
public enum CarModel
{
    M3 = 10,
    R8 = 211,
    Mustang = 3,
    Passat = 4
}
public enum CarType
{
    Sedan = 3,
    Coupe = 10,
    Convertible = 21
}
```

Of course you would want to do some error checking and etc. One drawback of Enums is that you're at the mercy of C# field naming requirements, and perhaps style-cop, and so it might make sense to have a property or utility method that goes to a string resource (like a RESX) and returns a "FriendlyBrandName" or something.

Comment: I believe this solution would only apply if code generation is in mind, as an enum can't be populated during runtime. This would also invalidate the possibility of having other fields rather than an id/value without resorting to a support class.